# How to do return types on methods in COM?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I know COM is old now, but every now and then we have to do some work on it. I was working on an ATL COM application in Visual Studio, I tried to add a method to an Interface, but it won't let me change the return type from HRESULT to something else like long or BSTR.

I can't recall exactly how it was done, may be through some out parameters. Can someone tell me how we do return types in COM Interface Methods ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return type in COM is always HRESULT (except special methods AddRef and Release), so you need to use `out` parameter:

```
HRESULT GetString([out] BSTR* val);
```

Also you can add `retval` attribute to turn the output parameter into the return value for script languages (that uses IDispatch):

```
HRESULT GetString([out, retval] BSTR* val);
```

Comment: Is it going to be treated as Return value when used in compiled language through IDispatch interface ? I am looking to use it like "string s = GetString()" in the target language

Comment: Ok I found it. It is [out, retval]

Comment: Return type is not always HRESULT in COM. I can be simple types (INT, BOOL) or basically anything as long as something can marshal it correctly (ex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370234.aspx). It's however recommended.

Comment: Non HRESULT methods are always local and cannot be marshaled. So technically you are right but it is not a real COM. A quote from MSDN: ["Non-[local] object interface member functions must have a return value of HRESULT or SCODE."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367124(v=vs.85).aspx)